# Splitting list of n element into one dataframe of n vectors

Tags: r

I have a list which contains say r of 5 elements of unequal length

> r

```
$First
[1] "Jan"   "feb"   "March" "Ram"  

$Second
[1] "Jan"   "feb"   "April"

$Third
[1] "Jan"   "feb"   "May"   "Shyam"

$Fourth
[1] "Jan"  "feb"  "June" "abcd" "July"

$Fifth
[1] "Jan"     "feb"     "asdfgg"  "dfhfhsa" "qwer"
```

Now I want to convert this list into a data frame of five vectors after deleting the first two common values.

I have tried a long method. Firstly I converted each element of a list into a single data frame and then sliced the first two values.

```
we<-r$First[3:4]

me<-r$Second[3]

er<-r$Third[3:4]

rt<-r$Fourth[3:5]

ty<-r$Fifth[3:5]
```

I believe there is another way to solve this. I am new to R, I couldn't find out.

The output should look like

```
   First   Second  Third   Fourth   Fifth    
1  March   April    May     June     asdfgg
2  Ram    NA        Shyam    abcd    dfhfhsa
3   NA    NA          NA      July    qwer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the two common values first using `Reduce`, then remove them from each list element using `sapply` and convert the remaining elements to dataframe by subsetting

```
common_vals <- head(Reduce(intersect, r), 2)
r1 <- sapply(r, function(x) x[!x %in% common_vals])
n <- max(lengths(r1))
data.frame(sapply(r1, `[`, 1:n))

#  First Second Third Fourth   Fifth
#1 March  April   May   June  asdfgg
#2   Ram   <NA> Shyam   abcd dfhfhsa
#3  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   July    qwer
```

**data**

```
r <- list(First = c("Jan","feb","March","Ram" ), Second = c("Jan","feb","April"), 
      Third = c("Jan","feb","May" ,"Shyam"), 
      Fourth = c("Jan","feb" ,"June","abcd","July"), 
      Fifth = c("Jan","feb","asdfgg","dfhfhsa","qwer"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `tidyverse` by `discard`ing the `list` elements having `intersect`ing elements and convert the unequal `list` lengths to a `matrix` with `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
map(r, ~  discard(.x, .x %in% reduce(r, intersect))) %>% 
   stri_list2matrix
#      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   [,5]     
#[1,] "March" "April" "May"   "June" "asdfgg" 
#[2,] "Ram"   NA      "Shyam" "abcd" "dfhfhsa"
#[3,] NA      NA      NA      "July" "qwer"
```

---

Or in a single line without pipes

```
stri_list2matrix(map(r, discard, `%in%`, reduce(r, intersect)))
```

#### data

```
r <- list(First = c("Jan", "feb", "March", "Ram"), Second = c("Jan", 
"feb", "April"), Third = c("Jan", "feb", "May", "Shyam"), Fourth = c("Jan", 
"feb", "June", "abcd", "July"), Fifth = c("Jan", "feb", "asdfgg", 
"dfhfhsa", "qwer"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to discard the first two elements of each vector and convert to `data.frame` then this should suffice:

```
nmax <- max(lengths(r))
data.frame(lapply(r, "[", 3:nmax))

#   First Second Third Fourth   Fifth
# 1 March  April   May   June  asdfgg
# 2   Ram   <NA> Shyam   abcd dfhfhsa
# 3  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   July    qwer
```